# Связь значения атрибута со значением тега span (оба элемента внутренние) в директиве angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Использую **angular 1.3.19**

Есть директива:

```
var directive = {
controller: 'ProductsListController',
restrict: 'A',
template: ['<div class="filter-wraper">',
                '<div class="price-label"><span id="jprice-min">$0</span><span id="jprice-max">$5,000+</span></div>',
                '<input id="ex2" type="text" class="price-input" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,5000]"/>',
            '</div>'
].join(''),
link: function ($scope) {
    $scope.priceSliderInit = function (){
        if ($(".catalog-page").length > 0) {
            $("#ex2").slider();
        }
    }
}
```

};

Нужно при изменении атрибута `data-slider-value` в `input` первое значение передавать в `span#jprice-min`, а второе в `span#jprice-max`.

Пробовал сделать ещё одну директиву в `input` и потом повесить `$observe` через `link`, но при попытке обращения к `attr` выдаёт "attr.$observe is not a function".

Код второй директивы:

```
var directive = {
   restrict: 'A',
   link: function($scope, elem, attr){
       attr.$observe('value', function(newValue){
           console.log(newValue);
       });
   }
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть ещё какие-то решения этого вопроса?

Comment: добавляй ng-model в Input, и следи за изменениями, или даже добавь `ng-change` на инпут и в обработчике выставляй переменные которые потом выводи вместо жестко забитых значений

Comment: по второй директиве: у функции `link` параметры _фиксированы_: scope, element, attributes, controller

Comment: @Grundy, в второй директиве подправил и исправил отслеживаемый атрибут (value должен быть). Но теперь показывается только первое значение. А вот ng-model не могу использовать, т.к. этот атрибут меняет Jquery плагин.

Comment: а почему не можешь-то? :-) в инпуте же все равно значение будет. Хотя надо просто поробовать :)

Comment: @Grundy, проблема в том, что в инпуте меняется программно сторонним плагином только атрибут value. Т.е. если привязать к нему ng-change, то он не срабатывает при изменении этого атрибута.

Comment: сделай пример тут в сниппете или на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) чтобы было видно процесс работы, какой плагин как работает и т,д.